# router.navigate() doesn't redirect inside .subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, router

I have a login function like so:

```js
login() {

  // clear error text
  this.state.errorText = "";

  // try to login
  this.sb.login(this.model.username, this.model.password).subscribe(x => {
    // check if ok
    if (x.success) {
      console.log('does this print') //<-- outputs as expected
      this.router.navigate(['/app']); 
    } else {
      this.state.errorText = x.response;
    }        
  });
}
```

Through debugger I can see the x.success comes back as true. My console.log prints but after, the this.router.navigate(...) line doesn't seem to do anything. there is no redirect.

I've tried to use:

```
this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/app']));
```

but that results in the same, no page redirect.

Comment: `navigate` returns a `Promise`, which you're ignoring.  It might be returning `false` or rejecting.  Consider handling the `Promise` to rule out these possibilities.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now!

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['app']).then(x => console.log(x)); ` only returns false, that must be the case. any advice @Alex Peters

Comment: It might be worth pasting your app's routing module into the question in case another pair of eyes can spot any small problem there.

Comment: @Alex Peters , im almost certain it's my auth gaurd, you've helped me think of a solution. thank you

Answer (score 0):

1 Assign Route Service Locally
2 Use the Assigned Local Service

```
login() {
  this.state.errorText = "";
  var route = this.router; // Assign router locally 

  // try to login
  this.sb.login(this.model.username, this.model.password).subscribe(x => {
    // check if ok
    if (x.success) {
      console.log('does this print') //<-- outputs as expected
      route.navigate(['/app']); // use local route service
    } else {
      this.state.errorText = x.response;
    }        
  });
}
```