# router.navigate() inside .subscribe halts functionality of the application

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to signin a user to my application and upon successful signin the user will get redirected to the home page (`/`).

Everything works fine here where the user gets redirected to the home page, but I am not able to navigate by clicking any links that are on the home page.

However, after examining the issue I noticed that, when I move the `this.router.navigate(['/'], { relativeTo: this.route })` out of the `subscribe` block in the `login` method (given below) the page gets redirected to the home page and all functionality seems to be working fine.

There is some issue with the way I am calling the `this.router.navigate` from the `subscribe` block. Can someone help me out discovering what is going on? Thanks.

Note: I also found a similar [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445488/router-navigate-doesnt-redirect-inside-subscribe). The suggested answer to assign `router` locally did not work.
Angular version - 11

```
login(pwd: any){
    this.loginService.login(usrname,pwd).subscribe(
    (response) =>
     {
          console.log("success executed");

          this.router.navigate(['/'], { relativeTo: this.route }).then(x => console.log("????? "+x));
        return;
    },
    (error) => 
    {
         console.log("ERRR  == "+JSON.stringify(error));

    }
   );

}
```

UPDATE

APP ROUTING MODULE.

```
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./home-page/home-page.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule) , pathMatch:"full"},

  {
    path: 'signup',
    loadChildren: () => import('./Reg/Reg.module').then(m => m.RegModule) 

  },
```

RegRoutingModule

```
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SignUpComponent },
  { path: 'signin', component: SignInComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RegRoutingModule { }
```

When User decides to signin to the application, they go into the Signup page (`SignUpComponent` ), and then click on the link SIGN IN (`SignInComponent` ). This is a lazy loaded module.

The Homepage component is also a lazy loaded module.

UPDATE 2

HomePageRoutingModule

```
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page.component';


const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomePageRoutingModule { }
```

UPDATE 3

```
   <div  >
       <a [routerLink]="['profile/8']" routerLinkActive="active"> Go to Page 2</a>

       <button (click)="navigateToProfile(profId)" >
                                    profile
       </button>
   </div>




navigateToProfile(profId: number) {

this.zone.run(() => {
  
  this.router.navigate(['profile/'+profId] );

});
```

Note: I have also tried it without using `this.zone`. Still the same result. Can this issue be something unique to Angular 11 ?

Note: This issue only occurs when the page is navigated from `subscribe` otherwise it will work.

UPDATE 4

Web service

```
 SignIn(signinModel: SignIn): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.httpClient.post<SignInResponse>(this.host + "/api/Sign", JSON.stringify(signinModel), { responseType: "json" })
      
     .pipe(map(e => {
       localStorage.setItem("user", e.token);
       return e != null ? true:false;
     }));
    
  }
```

If I comment the line `` it all works fine. Adding the token to localstorage seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update2:**

`localStorage.setItem("user", e.token);`

Is `e.token` a string or an object? If it's an object, you should serialize and de-serialize it with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` since, as per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), localStorage and sessionStorage can only hold string key/value pairs.

So if you change your code to this, it might solve the issue:

```js
.pipe(map(e => {
       localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(e.token));
       return e != null ? true : false;
     }));
```

and later load it like this:

```js
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

**Update:**

Ok, so after a lot of trial and error, my guess is that all the subsequent navigation issues, after you get to the Home page, are caused by the `pathMatch:"full"` of `path: ''` from `app-routing.module.ts`. I'm not able to reproduce the issue you have with subscribe, but the whole issue is pretty much related to the relative routing system. So just try commenting out that `pathMatch:"full"` flag and see how it goes.

Btw, I've created this test project in stackblitz where I tried to replicate your actual project. Take a look also over it and see if you see anything missing in your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqrxbc?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts

---

Most likely it's a problem of routes configuration, or even of some route guards that act in an unexpected way.

Are you using eager or lazy loading for  your `HomeComponent`? Showing the module where you configure your routes would be helpful, and I bet that the problem lies in there.

---

Also, I'm confused why you need to use `{ relativeTo: this.route }` when you do the navigation. Ideally you wouldn't need any route scoping at this point.

Comment: I have updated my post with the information requested. Yes, both the sign in part and the homepage components are lazy loaded. I have tried removing `{ relativeTo: this.route }` , but i am seeing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, please add also the routing.module of home-page. So far in the code you've added, I don't see anything off.

Comment: I have added under update 2 . Please have a look.

Comment: @Illep Just edited my answer. Hope that what I was able to find will help you.

Comment: I am not sure. It works in your but not in mine. I also found a SO post which says angular will not load an already loaded page (since i am using lazy loading). Here's the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672013/angular-7-wont-start-navigation-no-errors-are-seen-any-tips-on-whats-wrong.

But I don't want to force a reload as the entire objective of using lazy loading goes. Is there anything you could point me to ?

Comment: You're right, without forcing it, Angular won't reload the page when navigating to the current route. So are you saying that it's not working for you, even after you remove `pathMatch:"full"` from `path: ''`? If yes, then there's something more specific to your code. How does the navigation code that you have on Home page look like? Are you using `[routerLink]` in html or `this.router.navigate()` inside the class? Can you also share that code?

Comment: I have tried both methods. I have also updated the post.

Comment: Honestly right now I'm out of clue, since I don't have your exact project in order to reproduce it. If you can edit my stackblitz example and put as much as possible from your angular code in there (including the part with the route configuration for the Profile component), and make your issue reproducible, I might be able to help you further.

Comment: I found the cause of it. See update-4. The issue occurs when I try to save the access-token to localstorage. `localStorage.setItem("user", e.token);`. However, I am still looking how to sort this issue.

Comment: @Illep I've added another update to my answer. I hope this time it really fixes your issue.

Comment: It did not work as I expected. however, I think I will have to debug further so I could provide better information. Thank you for all the help.